# compound-key as lookup function in clojure

Tags: clojure, lookup, compound-key

In clojure you can use both maps and keys as look up functions hence
`({:a 1 :b 2} :a)` and `(:a {:a 1 :b 2})` are both viable lookup functions.

Why then can you use a map as a lookup function for a compound-key but not the other way around?

This means `({[:compound :mebaby] 1} [:compound :mebaby]})` will return `1`, but `([:compound :mebaby] {[:compound :mebaby] 1})` will throw an error.

Comment: You may want to read [this chapter](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-17_retrieving-multiple-keys.asciidoc) of Clojure Cookbook. Maybe the surrounding ones as well.

Answer (score 2):

Keywords implement `IFn` as one of their features to make them convenient to use as keys. The fn they implement is a lookup for themselves in an associative structure argument. This is not the case for collections like your vector because they implement `IFn` to do lookup in themselves at the argument key.

So `({[:compound :mebaby] 1} [:compound :mebaby]})` asks the map what the value is for the key `[:compound :mebaby]`, which exists. But `([:compound :mebaby] {[:compound :mebaby] 1})` asks the vector what the value at the index `{[:compound :mebaby] 1}` is. That's not an integral number, so it can't be an index/key in a vector and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that: your *compound-key* is no longer a *keyword*. It is now a vector, though still an `IFn`, it only takes integers, say `i`, as arguments, returning the `i`th element of the vector.

I suspect what you really want is to extract value from a nested map, like extracting the String "c" from `{:a {:b "c"}}`. If so, these two forms are equivalent:

```
(get-in {:a {:b "c"}} [:a :b])
;=> "c"
((comp :b :a) {:a {:b "c"}})
;=> "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that you can use a ***key*** as a lookup function is incorrect. You can use a ***keyword*** as a lookup function. In your example `:a` is a keyword. And so it can be used as a lookup function. But `[:compound :mebaby]` is not a keyword, that's a vector. Vectors can't be used as lookup functions.